# Trying to record elevation with coordinates when collecting data with Mergin

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

I am using a Geode GNS3 connected to a samsung tablet running Mergin Maps to do some geological mapping in terrain which is fairly steep.  Elevation is pretty key for us and i've got a form where when i collect a data point, it automatically adds easting and northing by adding $x and $y to the default values in the widget form  (see picture).   I am having trouble finding a way to have elevation recorded.  Is there an expression I can put in the default value field that will access the elevation provided by the tablet/Geode?  Currently I have to switch to the geode connect app and write down the elevation manually.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: First image: circled in magenta is where i put $x or $y to have it default to the geometry value, but there is no equivalent for elevation]

[image: Second image: my form on the tablet where easting and northing are auto-filled but elevation is blank.]

Comment: Have you tried `$z`?

Comment: yes.   that's not an option.  I later realized that $x and $y is only accessing the coordinates of the point I had just digitized as well, not the actual x or y coordinates coming from the gps - Though when i digitized that point, the cursor was being fed info from the gps so it's still a valid point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own expression with python, then you can access a lot of gps information:

1. open the expression builder and add a new function with the function editor, call it get_elevation for example, and press Save and Load Functions:

[image]

2. then you have a new function `get_elevation()` in the expression builder which you can use as default value in your form

[image]

[image]

The code is something like this one:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def get_elevation(feature, parent):
    """
    get gps elevation
    """
    connectionRegistry = QgsApplication.gpsConnectionRegistry()
    connectionList = connectionRegistry.connectionList()
    if connectionList:
        GPSInfo = connectionList[0].currentGPSInformation()
        elevation = GPSInfo.elevation
        return elevation
```

If you want to get other information from GPSInfo it would be for example the HDOP:

```
hdop = GPSInfo.hdop
```

see: https://www.qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsGpsInformation.html#qgis.core.QgsGpsInformation

Comment: Thanks euroJam, I couldn't get this to work for me but then discovered that Mergin Maps has it's own built-in set of default values in feature forms.   Just by putting @position_altitude in the default field, it will record the elevation on any new point once loaded in Mergin.   I will keep your answer in my back-pocket however if I ever need to do this within QGIS itself.  Cheers!